# Scraping data using cheerio and promise on node

Tags: javascript, api, promise, request, cheerio

I would like to be able to

- be able to get the data I am asking for
- be able to post it as a JSON file so I could loop through it and post it to a site.

I'm not currently getting any error messages.

I've tried using cheerio, promises, puppeteer and jsdom. I'm finding that every single time I can't get any data. I found most of how to build this template from https://www.donnywals.com/build-a-simple-web-scraper-with-node-js/

```js
// client-side js, loaded by index.html
// run by the browser each time the page is loaded

console.log("hello world :o");

// define variables that reference elements on our page

var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var Promise = require("promise");
var fs = require("fs");

request(
  "https://www.google.com/",
  function(error, result, html) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("An error occurred");
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }

    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var promises = [];

    $(".video-detailed-info .video-info-row").each(function(i, dataTable) {
      var race = $(dataTable)
        .find(".div")
        .text();
      var $userinfo = $(dataTable).find(
        ".usernameWrap .subscribers-count .pstar-list-btn .categoriesWrapper .productionWrapper .tagsWrapper .white"
      );

      promises.append(scrapeUnits($userinfo));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(promiseResults) {
      var data = {};

      // use the promiseResults to populate and build your data object...

      // write the JSON file to disk
      fs.writeFile("public/units.json", JSON.stringify(data), function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
);

function scrapeUnits(unitUrls) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfil, reject) {
    var units = [];
    units = $(".video-detailed-info..video-info-row.usernameWrap");
    unitUrls = document.querySelector("score");

    // some code that loads a new page with request

    // some code that uses querySelectors and cheerio to extract data
    // some code that creates a unit object and eventually adds units to the array

    // eventually we're done with grabbing data for our units and we do this:
    fulfil(units);
  });
}

// fetch the initial list of dreams

// a helper function that creates a list item for a given dream
```

```html
<p id = "score"></p>
```

Comment: `https://www.google.com/` makes no mention of `class="video-detailed-info"`. I'm not sure what you are trying to match.

Comment: Arrays don't have a method `append`. You probably meant `push`. So I would expect an error `promises.append is not a function` - are you sure you were looking in the right place for errors?

Comment: You don't need promises here. Cheerio doesn't use promises for anything because it doesn't do any I/O

Comment: @CherryDT what do you mean?